# How to set label on this jasper report on the colums where I have a small space for numbers?

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I have this chart below and I'm using this attribute:

to show them, but as you can see, in some places I don't have enough space to show this number, for example, 2014-10 or 2015-01. What can I do to fix that and show the value there?

[image]